# Pass parameter to function POST

Tags: php, jquery

I have two functions in JQuery,the first function will send the address ip to the script php indexFunctions.php.this address will be used by the second function JQUERY.I have succeeded to get address ipval with `.get`. Now I want to pass this @ip to the function `$_POST`with $rpi="http://".ip; but it not work when i set like this $rpi="http://192.168.1.15" it work.I get this error

```
Undefined variable: ip in /var/www/html/web/indexFunctions.php on line 36,
```

please help. thank you.

Script indexFunctions.PHP:

```
   if (isset($_GET['ipval']))
 {
    $ip=$_GET['ipval'];
  }
  $rpi="http://".$ip;
  if (isset($_POST['stbInfo']))
  {  

  if($_POST['stbInfo']=="On")
  {

   $url=$rpi.'/StbGetDataModel.php';}
```

Script index.PHP:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    setip(ip);
    stbStatus(stbInfo);
});

var ip = "192.168.1.15";

function setip(a) {
    $.get("indexFunctions.php", {
        ipval: a
    }, function(a) {
        $("#results").html(a);
        console.log(a);
    }, "html");
}

function stbStatus(a) {
    $.post("indexFunctions.php", {
        stbInfo: a
    }, function(a) {
        $("#StbInfo").html(a.text);
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: Where do these parameters from these functions come from ? `setip(ip);` `stbStatus(stbInfo);`

Comment: @Chay22 stbInfo = "<?php echo $RpiStatus; ?>" Rpistatus="on" and @ip=192.168.1.15

Comment: You mixin those 2 languages into one without separating it. I just confused within. What if you define var `ip` before you call `setip()` function. I'm affraid it becomes undefined.

Comment: No i don't mix the two languages i have a script named index.php who contains the function jquery and i have script indexFunctions.php if (isset($_GET['ipval'])).....

Comment: @chay22 I get this error "Undefined variable: ip in /var/www/html/web/indexFunctions.php on line 36, referer: http://localhost/web/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

> var ip = "192.168.1.15";

variable Ip must be declared first to use `setip(ip);`So yor code will look like

```
var ip = "192.168.1.15";//moved first
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    setip(ip);
    stbStatus(stbInfo);
});

function setip(a) {
    $.get("indexFunctions.php", {
        ipval: a
    }, function(a) {
        $("#results").html(a);
        console.log(a);
    }, "html");
}

function stbStatus(a) {
    $.post("indexFunctions.php", {
        stbInfo: a
    }, function(a) {
        $("#StbInfo").html(a.text);
    }, "json");
}
```

PHP code:

```
$ip     =   isset( $_GET["ipval"] ) ?   $_GET["ipval"]  : "127.0.1.1";
$rpi    =   "http://".$ip;
$url    =   ( isset( $_POST['stbInfo'] ) && $_POST['stbInfo'] == "On" ) ?   $rpi.'/StbGetDataModel.php' : $rpi.'/StbGetDataModel.php' ;
```

Comment: @ hemnath mouli Fri May 20 10:45:33.487367 2016] [:error] [pid 3347] [client 127.0.0.1:33089] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ip in /var/www/html/web/indexFunctions.php on line 37, referer: http://localhost/web/index.php

Comment: @Ktarizied I have updated the PHP can you try it now.?

Comment: I try it but it not works for the @127.0.1.1 when i put the address 192.168.1.15 it works but i search to pass the address like argument not fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (isset($_GET['ipval']))
  {
    $ip=$_GET['ipval'];
  }
  $rpi="http://".$ip;
```

If the Isset is FALSE he still try's to use $ip in line 4

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer when I use echo to display $rpi i obtain the exact url http://192.168.1.15